# перебор всех возможных комбинаций групп разделенных запятыми

Tags: php, рекурсия

Здравствуйте!
На входе имеем строку "abc", как на выходе получить массив:

```
[0] => abc
[1] => a,bc
[2] => ab,c
[3] => a,b,c
```

Размер строки заранее неизвестен. Заранее спасибо!

**UPD:** Господа, прошу прощения за неясность. Уточню:

На входе:

"abcdef"

На выходе:

```
[0] => abcdef
[1] => a,bcdef
[2] => ab,cdef
[3] => abc,def
[4] => abcd,ef
[5] => abcde,f
[6] => a,b,cdef
[7] => a,b,c,def
[8] => a,b,c,d,ef
[9] => a,b,c,d,e,f
[10] => ab,cdef
[11] => ab,c,def
[12] => ab,c,d,ef
[13] => ab,c,d,e,f
...
[n] => abc,d,e,f
...
[n] => a,bcd,ef
[n] => a,bcd,e,f
...
[n] => abc,de,f
...
[n] => a,bcde,f
...
```

В общем все возможные варианты куда можно вставить запятую между буквами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотите рекурсию? Пожалуйста:

```
function f($a) {
    $result = array();
    if (strlen($a) <= 1) {
        $result[] = $a;
    }
    else {
        $first = substr($a, 0, 1);
        $tail  = substr($a, 1);
        $arr   = f($tail);  // <<<=== Рекурсия здесь.
        foreach ($arr as $v)
            $result[] = $first . $v;
        foreach ($arr as &$v)
            $result[] = $first . ',' . $v;
    }
    return $result;
}

// Проверка.
foreach (array('', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde') as $str) {
    echo('<hr>');
    foreach (f($str) as $s)
        echo($s . '<br>');
}
```

Вывод для `abc`:

```
abc
a,bc
ab,c
a,b,c
```

Comment: Отлично! это то, что нужно. Рекурсия была не обязательна, просто я не вижу решения без нее

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна тут рекурсия, ее лучше использовать в крайнем случае она туже циклов.

```
$str = 'abcdefg';
$result[] = $str;
$str2 = implode(',', str_split($str));

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str2)-1; $i+=2) {
    $index = strpos($str2, ',', $i);
    $result[] = substr($str2, 0, $index) . substr($str2, $index+1, strlen($str2));
}
$result[] = $str2;
var_dump($result);
exit;
```

Вывод:

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(12) "ab,c,d,e,f,g" [1]=> string(12) "a,bc,d,e,f,g" [2]=> string(12) "a,b,cd,e,f,g" [3]=> string(12) "a,b,c,de,f,g" [4]=> string(12) "a,b,c,d,ef,g" [5]=> string(12) "a,b,c,d,e,fg" [6]=> string(13) "a,b,c,d,e,f,g" }
```

Comment: мне кажется, что ваше решение не отражает задачи автора: abcdef => a,bcdef; ab,cdef; abc,def; abcd,ef; abcde,f;a,b,cdef;...

Comment: имеешь в виду направление?

Comment: $result[] = str_replace('-', ',', str_replace(',', '', substr($str2, 0, $index) .'-'. substr($str2, $index+1, strlen($str2))));

Comment: array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "abc" [1]=> string(4) "a,bc" [2]=> string(4) "ab,c" [3]=> string(5) "a,b,c" }

Comment: Нет ни чего сложного развернуть

Comment: Мне кажется, что здесь нужна рекурсия... если вы уверены в вашем решении, то почему у вас приводятся не все варианты решения, а лишь только часть из них, причем меньшая?...

Comment: Рекурсия нужна там где она необходима. Циклы и встроенные функции быстрей рекурсии и регулярок. Если ты знаешь лучшее решение просто опубликуй его.

Comment: Извиняюсь за неточность, обновил вопрос